# Elegant way of diff'ing two variables?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, diff, here-string

I have $a and $b. I want to run `diff` on those.

The best I have come up with is:

```
diff <(cat <<<"$a") <(cat <<<"$b")
```

But I have the district feeling that I am missing a clever Bash syntax to do that (as in "Why don't you just use foo?").

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`echo`. Clearly less weird.

```
#!/bin/bash

a="`seq 10`"
b="`seq 0 11`"

diff <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")
```

Comment: How do you use this in a bash script? Trying to output a diff of two strings using this syntax and I get "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: I figured out why I couldn't get it to work. Process substitution is a bash feature, which is usually not available in `/bin/sh`. My bash script had the wrong shebang. Was `#!/bin/sh` but should have been `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I am getting the same error even though I'm using `#!/bin/bash`, is there something I am missing?

Comment: @Loupax Are you maybe running the script with `sh scriptname`?

Comment: @Kusalananda You got me, I'll look up what shell `sh` actually is

Comment: @Loupax It does not matter what it actually is, if you have written the script for `bash`, you should run your script as `./scriptname` (with a correct `#!`-line) or with `bash scriptname`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Because of certain policies I can't call it directly but at least now I know what to look up. Thank you for the pointer! :D